# Download file with url that contains hash symbol inside

Tags: cmake, download, vulkan

I have a problem with download Vulcan SDK via CMake.

I wanna use `ExternalProject_Add` with proper `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND`.

```
ExternalProject_Add(vulcan
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND
        URL "http://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#sdk/downloadConfirm/1.1.130.0/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.130.0.tar.gz"
        URL_HASH SHA256=ee044cefff9a92d4f3d10d4d87dc3070211ea2219da35612ee0adb24189cc354
    ...
    )
```

The problem is in above URL. It contains hash symbol which is treats as comment when I call `cmake` command on my `CMakeLists.txt`. This causes that CMake tries to download file from `http://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home`.

I tried to escape hash symbol with backslashes, but it seems not to work.

Do you have any ideas how to download file from url like this?

Edit (more info):

After I call make I have an error:

```
CMake Error at vulcan-stamp/download-vulcan.cmake:163:
  Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  End of file reached.
```

Problematic line in `download-vulcan.cmake`:

```
foreach(url http://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home#sdk/downloadConfirm/1.1.130.0/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.130.0.tar.gz)
```

This hash is treated as comment begin.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the hash as \#; ?

Comment: @Jherico Yes, but it doesn't work :|

Comment: This is not the actual download link. This is the link to a webpage that sends you to the actual download link.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, you're right. I've checked that in js on that page ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround for downloading Vulkan SDK.

There is another possible URL to use: `https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.1.130.0/linux/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.1.130.0.tar.gz`